# Constructing a smooth maximal atlas

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Firstly consider the following notations and definitions:

---

**Notation:** Let $(M,\mathfrak{A})$ be a smooth manifold. Then $\color{red}{\tau_M(\mathfrak{A})}$ denotes the topology in $M$ induced by the maximal atlas $\mathfrak{A}$.

**Definition:** Let $(M,\mathfrak{A})$ a smooth manifold. Suppose that $E$ is a set and $\pi :E\to M$ is surjective map. We say that $(U,\varphi )$ is a **local trivialization of $\pi$ with rank** $r$ if the following propositions are true:

1. $U\in \tau_M(\mathfrak{A})$
2. $\varphi :\pi ^{-1}[U]\to U\times \mathbb{R}^r$ is a homeomorphism with respect to the topology $\{\pi^{-1}[O]\cap \pi ^{-1}[U]:O\in\tau_M(\mathfrak{A})\}$ in $\pi ^{-1}[U] $ and the product topology of $\tau_M(\mathfrak{A})$ with the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^r$;
3. $\pi =\pi _1\circ \varphi $ in which $\pi _1:U\times \mathbb{R}^r\to U$ is given by $\pi _1(x,y):=x$;

---

**My question is:** How can I prove the proposition below?

**Proposition:** Let $(M,\mathfrak{A})$ be smooth manifold with dimension $m$. Suppose that the following propositions are true:

1. $\pi :E\to M$ is surjective map in which $E$ is any set;
2. There's a collection $\big\{(U_i,\varphi _i)\big\}_{i\in I}$ of local trivializations of $\pi$ with rank $r$ such that $M=\cup_{i\in I}U_i$ and for all $i,j\in I$ the map $\varphi _i\circ \varphi^{-1}_j:(U_i\cap U_j)\times \mathbb{R}^r\to (U_i\cap U_j)\times \mathbb{R}^r$ is a smooth map with respect to the obvious product manifold.

Then there's is a smooth maximal atlas $\mathfrak{E}$ such that $(E,\mathfrak{C})$ is a smooth manifold with dimension $m+r$ and $\pi :E\to M$ is a smooth map.

---

What I did:

I proved the above proposition. However the length of my proof may hide errors that I'm not being able to notice (so that proposition may even be false).

For this reason I would like to know if there is a simpler proof. **Also I would like to know** if there is a book that contains the proof of the previous proposition.

If that proposition is true, then $(\pi ,E,M)$ is a vector bundle because we can construct a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure in $\pi^{-1}[p]$ for all $p\in U_i$ and $i\in I$ such that $\varphi _p:\pi^{-1}[p]\to \mathbb{R}^r$ given by $\varphi_p (x):=\pi _2\circ \varphi_i (x)$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces in which $\pi _2:U\times \mathbb{R}^r\to \mathbb{R}^r$ is given by $\pi _2(x,y):=y$.

---

**Below is a sketch of my proof:**

Let $i\in I$ be any element.

Let $(V_i,\psi _i)$ be $m$-chart of $(M,\mathfrak{A})$ such that $V_i\subseteq U_i$.

Define $\psi _i\times \text{id}_r:V_i\times\mathbb{R}^r\to \psi [V_i]\times \mathbb{R}^r$ by $(\psi _i\times \text{id}_r)(x,y)=(\psi _i(x),y)$. It's easy to show that this map is smooth.

We can show that $\varphi_i |_{\pi ^{-1}[V_i]}:\pi ^{-1}[V_i]\to V_i\times \mathbb{R}^r$ is a homeomorphism.

Define $\sigma _i:\pi ^{-1}[V_i]\to \psi_i [V_i]\times \mathbb{R}^r$ by $\sigma _i(x):=(\psi _i\times \text{id}_r)\circ \varphi _i(x)$.

We can show that $\big\{(\pi ^{-1}[V_i],\sigma _i)\big\}_{i\in I}$ is a smooth atlas of $E$ (see the hypothesis 2 of the "Proposition" above). So there's a smooth maximal atlas $\mathfrak{E}$ such that $(E,\mathfrak{E})$ is a smooth manifold with dimension $m+r$.

We can also show that $\varphi _i:\pi ^{-1}[U_i]\to U_i\times \mathbb{R}^r$ is a smooth map using the manifold $(E,\mathfrak{E})$.

Since $\pi |_{\pi^{-1}[U_i]}=\pi _1\circ \varphi _i$ for all $i\in I$ and $\pi_1$ is smooth, then we can prove that $\pi :E\to M$ is indeed smooth.

Comment: I found a proof in the book "Introduction Smooth Manifolds" written by John M. Lee (see the Lemma 10.6 in the page 253).

Comment: I found another proof in the book "Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics" written by Gerd Rudolph and Matthias Schmidt (see the section 2.2).

Comment: Please notice that Lee's proposition is different than what you claimed. Lee doesn't talk about homeomorphisms with the inicial topology, as you do. He only requires bijections which induce fibrewise linear isomorphisms (for which you need $E$ to be a union of vector spaces). Only then he induces the topology on $E$ using these bijections. I'm glad you found what you were looking for.